# Injecting Services Or Executing Services After DeviceReady using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, angularjs-service

I have a cordova based plugins which access device contacts.
i have seen ng-cordova suggests to use deviceready to init the plugins in a controller.

My question is. is there is a way to inject services into angular.module after device ready is done so that i dont have to check deviceready for all the plugins all the time.

Answer (score 1):

@Siddharth,
to use *Cordova/Phonegap* you *MUST* wait until `deviceready` fires. To be clear for your question, `deviceready` only fires once.

READ: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

I QUOTE #4

*(...) points to the [section of documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) we need.*

> This is a very important event that every Cordova application should use.
>
> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However, JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web application could, potentially, call a Cordova JavaScript function before it is loaded.
>
> The Cordova `deviceready` event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova function.

*And in case you think this is minor, even veterans like [Raymond Camden](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/07/15/fyi-cordova-events-must-be-run-after-deviceready) have forgotten this.*